# Sieve of Eratosthenes java prime number if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, statements

I am trying to do the Sieve of Eratosthenes using a for loop then an if statement by checking for prime numbers up to 30 however I have a problem. Because of my code 2,3 and 5 are all shown as not prime numbers because they are divisible by 2,3 and 5 of course. How do I edit my code to make these come up as prime numbers?

Here is my code

```
public class prime {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int a=2; a<=30; a++){
        if(a%2 == 0 || a%3 == 0 || a%5 == 0){
            System.out.println(a +" = Not Prime");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(a + " = Prime");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Hint: you have got the definition wrong.

Comment: @MDSayemAhmed: But for values up to 30, it'll do.

Comment: The next number not yet crossed out in the list after multiples of 5 is 7; the next step would be to cross out every 7th number in the list after 7, but they are all already crossed out at this point, as these numbers (14, 21, 28) are also multiples of smaller primes because 7*7 is greater than 30. The numbers left not crossed out in the list at this point are all the prime numbers below 30:

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` statement to explicitly test for `a` being 2,3 or 5 before you test for divisibility.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a *prime* is that it is not divisible by another natural number other than `1` or itself. So, you need to devise a test for this, e.g., `a != 2`, etc., or, `a / 2 != 1`. In your code:

```
if (a != 2 && a % 2 == 0 || ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I added some code in in the if statement to check if its 2, 3 or 5.

```
public class prime {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int a=2; a<=30; a++){
        if(**a != 2** && a%2 == 0 ||**a !=3** && a%3 == 0 ||**a != 5** && a%5 == 0){
            System.out.println(a +" = Not Prime");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(a + " = Prime");
        }
    }
}
```

}